# Id must be assignable to Serializable With LAZY @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-data-rest

When I have entities having following -

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "question", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
```

I get below error. The error goes away however after making only @ManyToOne associations as EAGER, leaving bidirectional @OneToMany as LAZY.

**How to make this work with LAZY @ManyToOne with Spring DATA REST**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Id must be assignable to Serializable! Object of class [null] must be an instance of interface java.io.Serializable
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.support.RepositoryEntityLinks.linkToSingleResource(RepositoryEntityLinks.java:160)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.getSelfLinkFor(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:203)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.wrap(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:107)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.toResource(PersistentEntityResourceAssembler.java:84)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController$1.apply(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:141)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController$1.apply(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:110)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.doWithReferencedProperty(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:464)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.followPropertyReference(RepositoryPropertyReferenceController.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:769)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1125)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1059)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:539)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Error on URL : /api/users/2/question

```
{
  "cause" : null,
  "message" : "Id must be assignable to Serializable! Object of class [null] must be an instance of interface java.io.Serializable"
}
```

Comment: As it seems there is an open issue - https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-269

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue now seems to be solved in 1.8 M1 release.
As mentioned in [JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-630),

> "Be sure to add  to add Jackson Hibernate 4 module to the classpath to
>   let Jackson render proxies appropriately."

Comment: I used above 1.8M1 of Spring data JPA with ackson-datatype-hibernate4 2.4.4. and spring-data-rest-webmvc 2.3.0.M1 without success. Though some URL were working but not all and here is related question. I found some ManyToOne sides giving content:null. Their ResourceProcessor were being called but no query could be seen in log for related resource. I finally moved to using @JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"}) in entities at OneToMany Side with @AccessType(Type.PROPERTY)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647672/blank-screen-even-though-log-has-results-for-manytoone-lazy-associated-resource

Comment: is this in spring boot 1.3.RELEASE or have to add an entry for spring data jpa dependency

Answer (score 0):

`Fetch` in `@ManyToOne` annotation is optional so why to care about this.
`@ManyToOne` annotation defines a single-valued association to another entity class that has many-to-one multiplicity. So try following scenario.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="childTable_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
```

If you want to work that with lazy initialization so Try this,

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumn(name="childTable_id", nullable = false, referencedColumnName="id")
```

Comment: This did not help and I already had above JoinColumn in place with referencedColumnName and I get same error, changing from LAZY to EAGER has this side effect that a Join will be done even when it might not be necessary